# Multiline ddl Custom Control

Tags: c#, asp.net, custom-controls

One of the guys I work with needs a custom control that would work like a multiline ddl since such a thing does not exist as far as we have been able to discover

does anyone have any ideas or have created such a thing before
we have a couple ideas but they involve to much database usage

We prefer that it be FREE!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We use a custom modified version of [suckerfish](http://www.google.com/search?q=suckerfish) at work. DB performance isn't an issue for us because we cache the control.

The control renders out nested `UL`/`LI`s either for all nodes in the `web.sitemap` or for a certain set of pages pulled from the DB. We then use [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) to do all the cool javascript stuff. Because it uses such basic HTML, it's pretty easy to have multi-line or wrapped long items once you style it with CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [EasyListBox](http://www.easylistbox.com/home.aspx).  I used on a project and while a bit quirky at first, got the job done.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what you mean by multi-line, but if it is selecting multiple elements in a drop down list, see this [demo](http://www.easylistbox.com/demoMultiDropdown.aspx).

If its showing elements that wrap mulitple lines in a  drop down, see this [demo](http://www.easylistbox.com/demoCustomized.aspx).  You can put a break in the HTML to achieve what you might be looking for.  I've used this control in this manner before, so I can confirm it works.

Good luck.